# Making Class Booking system PHP

Tags: php, database, validation, time, comparison

I need help with my php script. I am working on a script that allows my users to choose a time for their class. The time list is locked on a 24 hour grid, meaning a class can only happen every hour.

**The goal of this script is to show the user a simple form with the available times.**

There are 24 possible times in a day **for one room.** **I have three rooms.**

I understand how to make the form later on, what I don't get is how to show available times if there are three rooms.

Here is what I got so far:

```
<?php
include 'db-connect.php';
if (isset($_GET['month']) && isset($_GET['day']) && isset($_GET['year'])) {

    $month = $_GET['month'];
    $day = $_GET['day'];
    $year = $_GET['year'];

    //string together date
    $date = $month."/".$day."/".$year;

    //return classes on this date
    $sql = mysql_query("SELECT start_time, server FROM classes WHERE date = '$date'");

    if (mysql_num_rows($sql)<=0) {

        echo "show all the times.";

    }else {

        $timelist = array(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24);
        $servers = array(1,2,3);

        while($query = mysql_fetch_array($sql)) {

                unset($timelist[$query['start_time'] - 1]);

        }
    }
}
?>
```

Database Example:

```
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| classID | trainerID | type | date      | start_time | duration | server | define      |
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| 1       | 1         | 12   | 08/7/2011 | 9          | 60       | 1      | dummy class |
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: I think I'm too stupid for this question. But I can help you a little.. $timelist = range(1, 24); a neater way for your long arrays. And maybe you can provide an example of the db table?

Comment: well my db table is named classes and my columns are: classID (auto increment), date (looks like 00/00/0000), start_time (1 - 24), duration (could be 15 - 60 mins), and server (1, 2, or 3).

Comment: http://sql-info.de/mysql/examples/CREATE-TABLE-examples.html and add this to your question.

Comment: Basically, you see those examples there. How to show the structure of the db. If dealing with mysql db related questions, then correct db example is necessary for quicker response :)

Comment: Ok, things are looking much better now. However, since I'm dumb. Then I need to get this clearer for my little brain. Whats in the table -- available times, when class is taking place or taken times, that is locked? So as I see, you will delete the time in the array.. Later on display the array with only available times.

Comment: The column start_time is the time at which that class is taken. It is 1-24 (military time). So when I call mysql_query(SELECT start_time, server FROM classes WHERE date = '$date'") I am getting the unavailable times. And then like you said, I just remove the times that are taken from the array. I need a way for the script to check if that time is taken three times in a row before removing it from the array. The problem after this is say: Server 1 @ 9 is taken, but Server 2 and 3 it's available. How would I go about linking the server to the time the user chooses?

Comment: Ok, things are clear on the php part. However, what is your form gonna look like? I probably can find you a solution but I'm too lazy to make the form part.. So basically, I need to know how your form will work later.

Comment: Here is a quick example I put together. http://www.phpform.org/formbuilder/view.php?id=864c8edd23ad543a05d35ba49917a751

Comment: Another thing is how do I go around converting military time into AM/PM?

Comment: Oeh, this is gonna get more deeper and deeper. You don't have enough rep to chat either. So find me on facebook or email me your msn. I because you have many problems at once actually and your methods could use some improvement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of your current strategy you could just store the number of arrays each time is found in, like:

```
//define time list
$timelist = array_fill(1, 24, 0);

while($query1 = mysql_fetch_array($sql1)) {

    $timelist[$query1['start_time']]++;

}

while($query2 = mysql_fetch_array($sql2)) {

    $timelist[$query2['start_time']]++;

}

while($query3 = mysql_fetch_array($sql3)) {

    $timelist[$query3['start_time']]++;

}

$timelist = array_keys(array_filter($timelist, 'equals3'));

function equals3($x){
    return $x == 3;
}
```

Now $timelist is an array of times that were found in all three queries. If you want an array of times that were missing from at least one query use this instead of the last few lines:

```
$timelist = array_keys(array_filter($timelist, 'lessThan3'));

function lessThan3($x){
    return $x < 3;
}
```